# Creating bounding box in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, extents

I am trying to create a bounding box for my map in ArcGIS 3.28. I want the bounding box to stay in a given area based on the coordinates given. I found a class called Extent in the API Reference that can set a bounding box, but it does not look like there's a way to implement the bonding box. This is what I have at the moment:`

```
var map;

  require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/dijit/InfoWindowLite",
    "esri/InfoTemplate",
    "esri/config",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "esri/geometry/Extent",
    "esri/dijit/Search",
    "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
    "esri/SpatialReference",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ],

  function(
    Map,
    InfoWindowLite,
    InfoTemplate,
    esriConfig,
    FeatureLayer,
    domConstruct,
    Extent,
    Search,
    ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer,
    SpatialReference
  ){

     var boundingBox = new Extent(-122.3737, 37.454, -121.467, 37.9067, new SpatialReference({ wkid:4326 }));

       //creating the map
     map = new Map("map", {
       extent: boundingBox,
       basemap: "streets",  //For full list of pre-defined basemaps, navigate to http://arcg.is/1JVo6Wd
       center: [-121.91, 37.65], // longitude, latitude
       zoom: 11
     });
```

Using this, is there a way to create a bounding box or is something I can add to it to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to create the bounding box. Here is the code I used:

```
        var boundingBox = new Extent(-122.3737, 37.454, -121.467, 37.9067, new SpatialReference({ wkid:4326 }));

        //create a map
        map = new Map("map", {
            extent: boundingBox,
            basemap: "streets",  
        });

        //bounding box
        var previousExtent = map.extent.getExtent();
        map.on("extent-change", function(){
            let currentExtent = map.extent.getExtent();
            if (boundingBox.contains(map.extent.getCenter())){
            // Update previous extent
                previousExtent = map.extent.getExtent();
            }
            else {
            // if new extent is not in bounding box then reset to previous extent.
                map.setExtent(previousExtent);
            }
        })
```